# Shopware 6 Using fontawesome in custom theme

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need to use fontawesome in my custom theme.
Therefor I installed it by using yarn `yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

When I'm trying to import it (`@import "~@fortawesome"` ) within the base.scss of my theme I get the following error:

> In ThemeCompiler.php line 317:
> [Shopware\Storefront\Theme\Exception\ThemeCompileException]
> Unable to compile the theme "CustomTheme". `~@fortawesome` file not found for @import: custom/plugins/CustomTheme/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss on line 2, at column 1
> Call Stack:
> #0 import custom/plugins/CustomTheme/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss (unknown file) on line 409

Can someone please tell me how to import fa correctly into my scss-file?

---

**EDIT:**
I installed fontawesome via npm inside my plugin under the following path `plugin/src/Resources/app/storefront`.

To import it in my base.scss I can't simply use `./@fortawesome/...` like descirbed in the [doc](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/scss). I have to import the files like this `../../node_module/@fortawesome/...` instead.

The other problem is that the system can't find/load the webfonts of fa. I know that a solution would be to copy the fonts manually into my public folder but is there a way to make shopware copy them and put them into the public folder throughout the compiling process?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73195414/shopware-6-add-styles-from-npm-package

Answer (score 4):

It's working. Here is what I've done:

- I installed fa via npm into the following folder **src/Resources/app/storefront**
- I added the important paths to the theme.json (fontawesome, regular,solid, and brands to style and webfonts to assets)

Is this the way shopware wants fa to be implemented in a custom plugin?